# In IE8, how do you make it ignore the Browser Mode setting?

Tags: internet-explorer, ie8-browser-mode

In IE8, if you use Developer Tools, you can specify your Browser Mode and your Document Mode, and it overrides its default behavior.  This can be very helpful, but I have a problem.

I am trying to see the default behavior, not what I set in Developer Tools.  Is there a way to disable Developer Tools so I can see what it looks like to everyone else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Developer Tools override only applies when you change it. You can close the browser and restart it to go back to the default behavior.